# google oauth2 C#: no refresh token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

in my C# application, I am trying to get aouth2 access and refresh tokens:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

On the phase: **Handling the Response**, When I make the call I am supposed to get something like:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

but I get

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
}
```

Thus: refresh_token is missing. I debugged and I am sure I hit the api method: **FetchAccessAndRefreshTokens** but I have no refresh_token.

PS: I am using 201306 API

Any ideas?

Comment: seems same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433990/when-authenticating-with-oauth-and-youtube-always-get-error-invalid-grant-on

Comment: please see the answer by mariuss:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317623/no-refresh-token-permission-to-access-data-while-offline-google-oauth/18342063#18342063

Answer (score 1):

In the API, within OAuth2ProviderForApplications.cs file, in GetAuthorizationUrl() method, on line 100 if you add **&approval_prompt=force** to the string:

return string.Format("{0}?scope={1}&state={2}&redirect_uri={3}&response_type={4}&" +
          "client_id={5}&access_type={6}**&approval_prompt=force**"

it works. But this is a horrible workaround plus it might create apache license issues.

How found: in google oauth2 playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) this parameter (approval_prompt=force) is set and if you omit it, it does not give refresh token.